# How to make scrollview height dynamic in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uistackview

Here is my structure:

```
-View
  -scrollview
    -view
      -stackview //main stackview
        -stackview1
          -label1
          -label2
        -stackview2
          -label1
          -label2
        -stackview3
          -label1
          -label2
        -stackview4
          -label1
          -label2
        -stackview5 // this is the dynamic vertical stackview
          -label1
          -label2 //this is the dynamic label
        -stackview6
          -label1
          -label2
```

I want the scrollview to be dynamic based on the stackview5. i set the label2 in stackview5 to 0 lines. i also set the distribution to equal spacing. what else am i missing?

Comment: What does "dynamic" mean?

Comment: @matt sorry i meant to say dynamic height.

Comment: You can fix the size of 1 `stackview`, and then based on the number of the stack views calculate the `contentSize` for `scrollView`.

Comment: Like this `[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, numberOfStackview * sizeOfOneStackView ))];`

Comment: Why do you need to set the content size if stack view height is updated using auto layout constraints and you only need to force update the scrollview, doesn't that will solve the problem?

Comment: Why do you care about the height of scroll view? It is a _scroll_ view! The user can _scroll_ it to see any part of it. That's the whole point. Its height does not have to change!

Comment: okay well something is wrong here then. the bottom scrollview5 and scrollview6 does not show up because of the height constraint. how do i fix this then?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UITableView

each of you six stackviews would be their own tableViewCell

Add this to the view did load of you TableViewController

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 58.0 // whatever you want your default to be 
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

add also this method to your TableViewController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: im not using a tableview. its a scrollview.

Comment: @pixie123 I know.  That is why I said that I would use a TableView.  It would make it easier.

Comment: I do not know of any downsides performance wise.  I would have to see what performance you are getting right now.  An upside is that the height is calculated for you.